# Chrome 81 mimetype change to file upload of audio/mp3

Tags: html, file, google-chrome, input

Prior to Chrome 81, when posting an audio file from a `file` input would result in a mimetype of `audio/mp3`.

As of Chrome 81, the mimetype is now `audio/mpeg`.

I can't see anything in the [release notes](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2020/04/nic81), so questions:

- Which one is correct?
- Should I support both `audio/mpeg` and `audio/mp3` server side (i.e. whitelisting types)
- Is there a way to force `audio/mp3` for this type?

### UPDATED

Answers to the above:

> Which one is correct?

`audio/mpeg` is referenced in the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3003) - so this should be used.

Comment: With what? The `<audio>` or `<source>` element? Is there a default mimetype?

Comment: I'm referring to `<input type="file"/>`  rather than using `<audio>` - the input _doesn't_ set an accept though.

Comment: This is for uploading an audio file, not displaying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks to be the case in chrome 81 as per the following commit:
[chromium/chromium/src/842f46a95f49e24534ad35c7a71e5c425d426550](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/842f46a95f49e24534ad35c7a71e5c425d426550)

Commit message reads as follows:

> Use audio/mpeg instead of audio/mp3 for .mp3 files
>
> audio/mpeg is used instead of audio/mp3 in safari and firefox for .mp3
> files, as defined in this rfc: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3003

Good find though.

Comment: That's it! I couldn't be bothered to look through the commits, thanks for doing that.